# Installing and running Qt quick app on S60 5th Edition

Tags: symbian, qml, s60, qt-quick, nokia-n8

I am new to Qt and I am developing an app for Symbian^3 platform using Qt Quick 1.1.
My app runs properly on Symbian^3 touch devices but when I installs on Nokia S60 5th edition then it installs but app could not run on these devices (S60 5th edition).

Also as described in this [link](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Symbian) Support for Symbian that S60 does not support Qt Quick 1.1 but if we installs any app using this library then it would first download Qt Quick and then installs Qt and then installs the app.

**When I installs my app on S60 devices (on RDA) then it first downloads and installs 5 different units using smart installer. And later installs my app but when I click on icon of my app then it does not run. What is going on any idea please?**

My app is almost complete I tested on Symbian^3 devices and it works fine but it never runs for S60 devices, so I am stuck to release app on ovi store.

**Does we need to build app in some different way specifically for S60?
Does same app sis file could not run on both Symbian^3 and S60 devices?**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Symbian^1 there is no Qt 4.7.4, only 4.7.3. So your import QtQuick 1.1 won't work, you have to use QtQuick 1.0.

And if you use the standard project files you probably can't install or run the Symbian^3 SIS files as is. But in the Qt Creator there is also a S60v5 build which you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please tell me of making build with s60v5 in Qt creator. as ti never shows s60v5 any where but it only shows symbian^1 4.7.3. Do you talking about to use this config for the build for s60 device and it would also work fine for symbian^3 devices. Please do response some.

Comment: Symbian^1 is S60v5. I think the Creator guys renamed the SDK with an update. Use that and the app should work on a S60v5 phone.

Comment: Thnak You, it worked with building app on symbian^1. It runs well on Symbian S60 v5 on RDA and on Symbian^3 devices too.